# current time on Server (AWS) different from real time

Tags: django, date, server, localhost, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

thanks for the help in advance.

I have a django/python project and deployed to AWS with elastic beanstalk. But there is an issue with the current time with the deployed version. I get the current time through django model and render it frontend. It's always one day behind, but it works fine on the localhost.

I have changed the localtime on the server under /etc/localtime to the desired timezone , but this does not address the issue.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out  the solution. The issue was that I used " now () " in my model form for initializing the value. I guess that will just take the server restart time and use it for every instance. It works  by removing the parentheses from the form field initialization part , this way the now function will be called for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the time of the server as it originally was, which I assume to be UTC.

And change your timezone in your project's settings file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago' # use your desired local timezone
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Thank you xyres,  I acutally do have these two in my settings, the only thing different from yours is that I used 'US/Central' instead of 'America/Chicago'. I suppose these should be the same?

Comment: I also tried different methods to initialize the date e.g. now vs. today . But they don't make a difference actually.

Comment: @user9785672 Django uses UTC to save objects in the database. And uses the `TIME_ZONE` settings to convert UTC to given timezone to display in the templates. I'm guessing, your server's hardware clock or OS timezone is either not in UTC or is out of sync. If you're running Linux, run `date` command to see OS time and run `sudo hwclock --debug` command to see hardware clock time.

Comment: Xyres, I found out the answer, thank you for the help!  My apologies that I did not provide code details. I have been considering this as a time zone config issue